# Image upload from front-end

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to upload image-file from frontend in OctoberCMS

I have a model Person and relation:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'photo' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

In php-block with upload form:

```
public function onUploadImage() {
    $person = Person::where('id', '=', $this->param('id'))->first();
    $person->photo = \Input::file('avatar');
    $person->save();
}
```

And my template:

```
<form method="POST" action="/persons/person/{{person.id}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onUploadImage">
<input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" />

{{ form_token() }}
{{ form_sessionKey() }}

<button type="submit" data-attach-loading>Upload</button>
```

After submit it saves to DB only path 'http://my-site/storage/app/uploads/public/' and does not upload any files to filesystem. It seems like there are no some permissions, but I can easily upload images from backend.

Where is my error?

Answer (score 2):

You must get the UploadedFile from the request and store it to one of the configured disks. And store the path to the image in the database.

Assume `storage/app/public/images` is the directory where the uploaded images should be stored.

```php
public function onUploadImage() {

    if(request()->hasFile('avatar') && request()->file('avatar')->isValid()) {

        $file = request()->file('avatar');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $person = Person::where('id', '=', $this->param('id'))->first();
        $person->photo = $file->storeAs('images', $filename)
        $person->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://octoclub.ru/d/258-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) is the solution.

```
if(request()->hasFile('avatar') && request()->file('avatar')->isValid()) {

        $file = new System\Models\File;
        $file->data = Input::file('avatar');
        $file->is_public = true;
        $file->save();

        $person = Person::where('id', '=', $this->param('id'))->first();
        $person->photo()->add($file);
        $person->save();
    }
```